# How to read a specific Worksheet with Openpyxl, instead of active sheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an **existing excel file**, with Data on the **first and second sheet**, I should **read** both with Python.

Openpyxl reads data from the first/active sheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
```

It works fine, until I am always on the first sheet.

I tried this:

```
wb.active = 1  # or
wb.active = 2
```

Didn't work.

I would like to read sheets not depending on activation, but based on the name of them. (Or Sheet position)
I need something like this:

```
wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.Sheet1
ws2 = wb.Sheet2
```

So, how can I read data from different sheets, without clicking on them?

Or, how can I activate the actually needed sheet?

Comment: This is covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use openpyxl to modify data in specific sheet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952548/how-to-use-openpyxl-to-modify-data-in-specific-sheet-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814050/get-sheet-by-name-using-openpyxl

Answer (score 3):

I found it!

```
ws2 = wb["Sheet2"]
```

And then I just call ws2 and it works well. :)
For Example:

```
ws2['A1'].value
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through wb.worksheets or wb.sheetnames, look up worksheet by index (1-based) or by sheet name. Here is sample script:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

input_file = 'inputs/my_sample.xlsx'  # update as needed
wb: Workbook = load_workbook(filename=input_file)

def get_worksheet_by_index(wb: Workbook, sheet_idx: int, set_as_active: bool = False):
    # sheet_idx is 1-based
    ws = None
    for idx, worksheet in enumerate(wb.worksheets):
        if idx + 1 == sheet_idx:
            ws = worksheet
            if set_as_active:
                wb.active = ws  # set current worksheet as the active worksheet
            break
    return ws


def get_worksheet_by_name(wb: Workbook, sheet_name: str, set_as_active: bool = False):
    ws = None
    for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
        if sheetname == sheet_name:
            ws = wb[sheetname]
            if set_as_active:
                wb.active = ws
            break
    return ws


ws = get_worksheet_by_index(wb, 2)
print(ws.title)

ws = get_worksheet_by_name(wb, 'my_sheet_name')  # update as needed
print(ws.title)
```